# Angularjs v1 vs v2 and release date for v2

Tags: angularjs, release

I was having a look at AngularJS v2 compared to v1 and I realized that the syntax is totally different in some cases. For example:

```
v1       |    v2
ng-model | [value]
ng-click | (click)
```

I was a expecting some form of consistency in syntax so we don't have to start writing syntax differently for each version.

- Does the changes in syntax help in anyway?
- What makes v2 better than v1?
- I will also want to know the release date for v2?

Comment: Get over it: angular 2 is another, different, framework. Nobody knows its final release date.

Comment: It's a complete rewrite, core concepts are still alive, but, 90% of ng has chagend

Comment: There is some major drawback is there in v1 so the team is rewriting it to overcome those. And it is not possible to keep ng-click and all like that. That is why it is a major migration nesseary to support v1 to v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a completely new framework, hence the change in syntax is nothing to be confused about.
If you want consistency you will have to stick with angular 1.x
1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 - they all provide consistency in syntax.
But the 2 in 2.x stands for major changes, so yeah - you will have to learn a new syntax and framework if you want to migrate.

- Yes the change of syntax does help. It is the result of an exact analysis of the disadvantages of angular1 by google. There are too many reasons to provide them all in this post. Probably you should just watch a video by google about angular2 where they handle these changes
- v2 is more intuitive and easier to learn. Furthermore it is way more performant in terms of large scale applications. And finally it's closer to modern standards like webcomponents.
  There are a few more advantages like server-side-rendering, etc. but to list them all would be too much for this post again, thus i recommend watching some google videos instead here as well.
- there is no release date yet, but you can use the official beta which is already ready to use in productive in my understanding. you can probably estimate that it will be officially released within this year, everything more precise would be pure idle speculation